# Append more than 100 products in Adobe Analytics

Tags: adobe-analytics

if i add more than 100 products under s.products in adobe analytics, I am seeing 414 status code

[image]

Comment: Is there a need to add 100+ products to s.products?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, since you got this error, and I see in your screenshot it is a GET request, it sounds like you may not be using the latest Adobe Analytics AppMeasurement library (AppMeasurement.js) and Experience Cloud ID Service (VisitorAPI.js) - or at least a version that supports POST requests. So the first thing I suggest is update to the latest libraries.

But second - and perhaps more importantly - as @RobertSim commented - what are you doing that requires pushing 100+ products to an AA hit? I've been doing this for over 10 years with countless clients both directly working with them and indirectly on help sites such as this, and this is the first time I have ever seen someone try to push so many products at a time.. I'm a little impressed.

But nonetheless you are almost certainly going about things the wrong way. Are you trying to do product impression tracking on a category/product listing page? There is no way a visitor is viewing 100+ products at a time. The standard is to do top 5 or top 10 on a category/product listing page.

Are you trying to push meta data about products to AA? Definitely should not be doing it like this. You should probably be using SAINT classification uploads.

Provide more details about what you're trying to do here, what's the goal of this, etc. and perhaps a better answer can be given.